# Google API : Blink background color of a column cell in table chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, google-visualization

Is it possible to blink background color of a cell based on the value. Say for example in below sample if salary is greater than 5000 and less than 10000 it should blink in red color background

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use table cell property `className` to give a cell a certain css class.

then just find the cells that meet the criteria and assign the class for blinking.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['table']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
  data.addRows([
    ['Mike', 10000],
    ['Jim', 8000],
    ['Alice', 12500],
    ['Bob', 7000]
  ]);

  // determine if salary is in blink range
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    var salary = data.getValue(i, 1);
    if ((salary > 5000) && (salary < 10000)) {
      // set blink class
      data.setProperty(i, 1, 'className', 'blink-cell');
    }
  }

  var container = document.getElementById('table');
  var table = new google.visualization.Table(container);

  table.draw(data, {
    allowHtml: true
  });
});
```

```css
.blink-cell {
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```